# How to Queue A Method Including Selenium In C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have one method in which I use selenium. I would like to queue every call of this method whenever one instance of it is already running. I use several variables that are set and dynamic inside the method.

If I were to call this method and an instance of it has already been initiated, it should wait until the current instance has finished its operations before it starts the method.

```
Public void Demo()
{
int f = 2; 
driver.Navigate.GoToUrl("www.google.com");
}
```

*I have experience with NUnit if someone has a solution including it